# REST Service response based on accept parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey, soapui, java-ws

I am looking to create a REST service compatible for XML as well as JSON Response. With the URI being similar for both. I need to provide response based on the accept header.

Is this possible with a single URI? IF possible, how do I set the @Produces?

Answer (score 1):

Reading javadoc of `@Produces`:

> Defines the media type(s) that the methods of a resource class or 
>   {@link javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter} can produce.  * If not specified then a container will assume that any type can be produced.

This means that this annotation just reduces number of supported media types. Otherwise the choice is done automatically.

Interface `MessageBodyWriter` has a lot of implementations for different media types. The concrete implementation is chosen into `MessageBodyFactory`:

```
public <T> MediaType getMessageBodyWriterMediaType(Class<T> c, Type t,
        Annotation[] as, List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes) {
    for (MediaType acceptable : acceptableMediaTypes) {
        for (MessageBodyWriterPair mbwp : customWriterListProviders) {
            for (MediaType mt : mbwp.types) {
                if (mt.isCompatible(acceptable) &&
                        mbwp.mbw.isWriteable(c, t, as, acceptable)) {
                    return MediaTypes.mostSpecific(mt, acceptable);
                }
            }
        }
        ......................
```

As we can see the first provider that supports the first of `acceptableMediaTypes` is chosen. Although IMHO the name `acceptableMediaTypes` is self explainable I continued my discovery and found the only place that calls this method:

```
        contentType = getMessageBodyWorkers().getMessageBodyWriterMediaType(
                    entity.getClass(),
                    entityType,
                    annotations,
                    request.getAcceptableMediaTypes());
```

where `request`'s type is `ContainerRequest`.

Here is the code of `getAcceptableMediaTypes()`

```
public List<MediaType> getAcceptableMediaTypes() {
    if (accept == null || headersModCount != headers.getModCount())
        accept = new ArrayList<MediaType>(HttpHelper.getAccept(this));

    return accept;
}
```

As we can see the list of media types is filled with result of `HttpHelper.getAccept(this)`:

`final String accept = request.getHeaderValue(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT);`

Bottom line: yes, the media type is chosen automatically according to HTTP header `Accept` unless hard coded annotation `@Produces` limits this.

Answer (score 0):

@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})

For JAX-RS implementations ...

Long ago that I used it, but I remember - and may still apply for certain implementations - that you need to add a customized MediaConfig to your Application. Buts it's definitely built in for JEE6/7.

And at that time I customized to respect file extension in request uri... Maybe header always worked.

Edit:
Just searched, probably wasn't called MediaConfig, I'll come back when I find / remember it and if it's still required.